# How do I remove zeros when averaging between tabs in excel?

Tags: excel, tabs

I am trying to average a series of number.  The numbers are on different Tabs

Tab 1:
1
2
3
4

Tab 2:
0
3
5
8

Tab 3:
5
0
0
2

I want to be able to do an average of cell A1 across the different tabs and remove the zero.  Is there a way to do this?  I have seen doing an averageif, but that only works if the cells are on the same tab.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Some features may have changed from Excel version to version; please supplement your question with which Excel version you are using.

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/672592-averageif-across-multiple-tabs.html `=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1:A1)/INDEX(FREQUENCY(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1:A1,0),2)` or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use, for tabs named `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`:

`=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1)/INDEX(FREQUENCY(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1,0),2)`

where `Sheet1` and `Sheet3` should be replaced accordingly, i.e. with, respectively, the leftmost and rightmost of the sheets to be queried.

Regards

Comment: what does the 2 mean in the index?

Comment: It's the row_num parameter. FREQUENCY will here return an array comprising two values; the first equal to the number of zeroes in cell A1 of the relevant sheets, the second equal to the number of non-zeroes in cell A1 of the relevant sheets, Clearly we require the latter for our denominator.

Comment: Actually non-zeroes was not correct. >0 would have been. Negative numbers in the ranges would cause this set-up to fail.

Comment: where does the >0  go?

Comment: Ah. So you DO have negative numbers in those ranges?

Comment: I don't have any numbers less than 0.  There are only 0 and above.

Comment: Ok, so now I'm a bit confused. Why did you ask "where does the >0 go?"?

Comment: Even though I don't need it, I was curious where you would put it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put the names of the desired sheets in a named range.  I named mine `sheets`.

[image]

Then you can use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(INDIRECT("'" & sheets & "'!A1")))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & sheets & "'!A1"),"<>0"))
```

[image]